# Importing a Google Group to bbPress

Tags: import, bbpress, bulk-import, google

I'm trying to migrate a google group to a bbPress forum on a wordpress site. I ran into this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-export-for-bbpress/ but it doesn't have a UI. This might be a dumb question from a complete newbie but how do I run a plugin without a UI?

**Update** I put the wrong plugin link for the import. I meant this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bbp-import-google-group/

Is there a better way to import the content of a google group to a new forum in bbpress?

I would have used `All Import` to do this (I ran into trouble doing that too) but I can't find a way to download the content of a public Google Group.

Comment: I haven't tried the plugin but from the source it has a few UI pages and looks like it adds a new admin menu option "Forums IM-EX". So there should be a UI.

Comment: Thanks! It seems there is a menu option under settings... Oddly it doesn't show in firefox, only in chrome on my machine....

Comment: Sorry, I placed the wrong plugin link: this is the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/bbp-import-google-group/

It has a link to click/run it but once this is done it doesn't really do much. I guess I need to edit the PHP code on the server to fix it

Comment: Yes, I suspect something's changed at Google's end and this will need some updates to work now. It's a start though, but I'd try and trace out all of the calls it's making to Google to see what's going wrong. Good luck!